Are pilots allowed to take laptops into the cockpit?
In response to one of my other question, a comment mentioned Northwest Airlines Flight 188, an incident where both pilots became extremely distracted after taking out their laptops. Although Flight 188 eventually landed safely without any problems, it nevertheless shows how much a pilot (or pilots, in this case) can be distracted if they start to do non-essential work on their Portable electronic devices (PEDs). This incident is a reminder of how important the sterile cockpit rule is. However, I have a question: why were the pilots even allowed to take their laptops into the cockpit? I mean, if they aren't allowed to use their PEDS for the entire flight, then there's no reason to carry them into the cockpit. Or are pilots actually not allowed to take their laptops or other PEDs in the cockpit, and that Flight 188's pilots violated this rule too? Also, are pilots today allowed to take their PEDs into the cockpit? If not, what kind of penalty may be enforced against such actions? I'll appreciate any help or explanations. Thanks in advance!

They aren't supposed to use it, but to use it once they've landed, they need to transport it right? So I don't think there would be any rule regarding having it in the cockpit.

A year earlier on Oct 1 2008, the Federal Railroad administration issued Emergency Order 26 banning non operational smart device use.  (Due to Chatsworth).  EO's are extremely rare, only one every few years.  Maybe USDOT's various administrations should read each other's highest priority bulletins.

The laptop being in the cockpit is absolutely allowed.  Having it turned on & in use during the flight for a purpose not related to the pilot's duties isn't.
In many aircraft, a pilot's bags (flight bag, suitcase, etc) are all stored on the flight deck, and it would be nonsensical to require that a laptop or other personal electronic devices be removed & stored elsewhere.  Many pilots bring laptops with them on their trips -- which can last for several days before returning home -- and use them during off-duty time for emails, movies, browsing, and so forth.  They're kept in some bag that is typically stored on the flight deck.

As of 14th April 2014 the FAA banned pilots operating under Part 121 from personal use of electronic devices and laptops while at a duty station.
Reference: The Federal Register
The rule also covers some Part 135 and Part 91 operations
Note that the rule does not prohibit the use of personal devices in connection with the operation of the aeroplane, nor does it prohibit use when not at a duty station, and for these reasons it is silent on whether the devices should be permitted on the flight deck. Specific operators may have their own rules
Note that I have not attempted to reproduce the full text of the rules here. You should take a moment to read the article linked above before asking more questions.
